# App Engine instance not starting with basic scaling but works with auto scaling

Tags: django, google-app-engine

I'm trying to start a project on App Engine with basic scaling but it won't start. The app works fine with auto scaling. `/_ah/start` returns a 200 when the app is in auto scaling. I cannot figure out why the app will only start when set up for auto scaling.

Here's `app.yaml`, this is a pretty standard app:

```
application: myapp
module: default
version: 1-1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon.ico

- url: /_ah/(mapreduce|queue|warmup).*
  script: wsgi.application
  secure: always
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: wsgi.application
  secure: always
```

And here's `background.yaml`, this is identical to `app.yaml` except for the instance class and scaling parameters:

```
application: myapp
module: background
version: 1-1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes
instance_class: B1
basic_scaling:
  max_instances: 1
  idle_timeout: 10m

libraries:
- name: lxml
  version: "2.3"

handlers:
- url: /static
  static_dir: static

- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: static/img/favicon.ico
  upload: static/img/favicon.ico

- url: /_ah/(mapreduce|queue|warmup).*
  script: wsgi.application
  secure: always
  login: admin

- url: /(mapreduce|tasks).*
  script: wsgi.application
  secure: always
  login: admin

- url: /.*
  script: wsgi.application
  secure: always
```

When the app is in auto scaling mode, /_ah/start returns OK and an HTTP code 200. When it's in basic scaling mode, all I see in the logs are repeated failed attempts to reach /_ah/start with a 400 HTTP code. Since these are running exactly the same code, I am at a loss to understand what's going on here. I'm probably missing something obvious... but I can't see it. Ideas?

-- UPDATED --

This is the exact output I see when I use `curl` to access the `/_ah/start` endpoint locally:

```
curl -i -X GET http://localhost:8000/_ah/start
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Cache-Control: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Content-Length: 3
Server: Development/2.0
Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 09:08:06 GMT

Ok.
```

... and on the server when set up with auto scaling:

```
curl -i -X GET https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/start 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Fri, 24 Jun 2016 09:11:41 GMT
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 3
Alternate-Protocol: 443:quic
Alt-Svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="34,33,32,31,30,29,28,27,26,25"

Ok.
```

... and on the server when set up with basic scaling it just hangs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the handlers built in to `djangae` are not doing something necessary for this to work, I'm not exactly sure what. Similar to GAEfan's suggestion, I provided a handler, though his does not allow the app to run in threadsafe mode, so here's the `background_starter.py` file I'm using:

```
import os
import webapp2

from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template


class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write('{"status":"OK"}')


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/_ah/start', MainPage),
], debug=True)
```

... and here's the update to the `.yaml` file to treat this as a stand-alone app:

```
- url: /_ah/start
  script: background_starter.app
  secure: admin
```

Comment: Without `login: admin`, any evildoer can startup your backend instance.

Answer (score 0):

Your wildcard handler is accepting the call to `_ah/start`.  You should add a handler for `_ah/start` in background.yaml:

```
- url: /_ah/start
  script: background_starter.py
  login: admin
```

Then, you can make a simple return for a 200.  In background_starter.py:

```
print 'Content-Type: text/plain'
print 'This is a dummy handler to return http 200, so you can use wildcard url mapping in app.yaml.'
```